# Include an extra file with installation to a specific directory

Tags: packaging, autotools, automake

I'm using automake to package my software, and I want to have the license installed to `/usr/share/licenses/mypackage` like the other software on my machine. Similarly, I intend to write a `.pc` file, since I am writing a library, and I would like it to be installed to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`.

I'm aware of the `EXTRA_DIST` flag, but from what I have read, it's rather clumsy and can include things you don't want. Is there another standard way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXTRA_DIST` will add files to the tarball that you create with `make dist`, but not install them to the system. This is what you want:

```
licensedir = $(datadir)/licenses/$(PACKAGE_NAME)
dist_license_DATA = LICENSE
pkgconfigdir = $(libdir)/pkgconfig
dist_pkgconfig_DATA = mylibrary.pc
```